# GPS from cell tower/GPRS to Pi

Tags: hardware, gps

I am trying to create a solution where my Pi sends GPS coordinates to a database server and at the same time keep my cost of items as low as possible.

I have the Pi and a USB dongle which I will be connecting to the internet to relay my position.

I have also ran into this link [Raspberry Pi Location Tracker](http://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-Location-Tracker/?ALLSTEPS#step1) which suggest that latitude and longitude can be gotten based on sim card/cell tower.

In your experience, will that be accurate enough? It doesn't have to *exactly* pin point but will I get accuracy for at least 100 meters? If it points the device is on a street... if it's on the next street over that is acceptable. Just not... two football fields away.

Comment: The link you mention assumes your USB dongle has a web interface with cell info.  Over the past 15 years I have played with many dongles, but I cannot recall even one of them having such an interface.  You probably have more chance to get this information via old fashioned AT-commands.

Comment: @EDP food for thought, but shouldnt all devices have a http://192.168.0.1/ page? but say it doesnt have one, can't i just use python to pull the needed information?

Comment: I suggest you use `AT` commands for getting stuff out of the dongle.  I won't use python for that.  Have a look at [atinout](http://atinout.sourceforge.net/). This is probably what the web interface uses anyway under the hood.  Mileage might vary on different modem brands/models.  `AT` commands specific for your model might not even be publicly available on the net.  Perhaps [Hayes command set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayes_command_set) might get you in the right direction

Comment: @EDP thanks for setting me on the correct path. However my ultimate goal is to take this latitude / longitude information and put it in a python script then make that script a crod. so every 5 minutes the sever will be uploaded with the information on the dog's collar

Comment: A dog with a Raspberry, USB Dongle and battery pack around his neck.  Please share a picture with us when he comes out of the puddle in the back of the garden.

Comment: @EDP haha I laughed. Just doing it for fun cause he likes to wander off for days. imagining the look on his face when he's out and we suddenly just appear our of the blue for him

Comment: If you're looking for a Pi project, go ahead with the above.  If you want something more turn key, google 'gps TK102'.  They're about $25 a pop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A-GPS is what you're talking about. It is not bad, but it depends on a place : in a busy city centre it can be even more accurate, than a normal/true GPS, because it lacks of satellite signals due to high towers/houses and there's usually more cell base stations around. But in an open places classical GPS is the best and more accurate, usually.

Comment: Thanks, apart from the link I posted, do you have any other resource that shows getting latitude / longitude from cell towers? want to get acquainted with the subject and read before my dongle gets here.